# HTTP gzip compression not working for css or javascript in tomcat 6

Tags: tomcat, compression, javascript, css

Connector settings:

```
<Connector ...
compression="2048"
noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
compressionMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript"/>
```

This seems to work for html, but not for css or javascript. compression="force" *does* work, but compression="on" doesn't. compression="2" doesn't work either, so I don't know what "force" is really doing.

The files in question are about 6k, I've cleared the browser cache, etc.

Comment: Note that in Tomcat 7 this is the default setting, with the addition of `application/javascript`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `compressableMimeType`, not compressionMimeType, so

```
<Connector ...
compression="1400"
noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
compressableMimeType ="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript"/>
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

Please use application/javascript instead of text/javascript, as given below:
`compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,application/javascript"`